# Is it illegal in the UK for a supermarket to not disclose all the ingredients in meat produce?

Tags: united-kingdom, food, food-processing

E.g. if a supermarket was selling chicken which contained traces of pork and they did not list it on the ingredients would that be illegal? (Not referring to allergens just ingredients in general).

Does anyone have a link to an official source for this e.g. gov.uk or food standards agency?

Thanks

Comment: How do you make chicken from pork?

Comment: @Nij they process chicken meat with the same machines and tools that they have used to process other meats, and while probably they do some cleansing regularly, they do not clean it fully -which may be a very long process involving disassembly- between batches.

Comment: That doesn't mean pork is an ingredient, though. I'm struggling to see how you can justify that traces from previous and separate work can then be required as a listed ingredient when none is added to the new product.